# How Can We Reference Kotlin Constants in a Java Annotation Declaration?

Tags: kotlin

Given this bit of Kotlin:

```
object OldTownRoad {
  const val COWBOY_HATS = "from Gucci"
  const val WRANGLER = "on my booty"
}
```

and this Java class:

```
public class Scrap {
  @Named(OldTownRoad.COWBOY_HATS)
  public void lilNasXrefs() {
    System.out.println(OldTownRoad.COWBOY_HATS);
    System.out.println(OldTownRoad.WRANGLER);
  }
}
```

The compiler is happy with the `println()` calls. It complains about the use of `COWBOY_HATS` in the `@Named` annotation, saying "Attribute value must be constant", as seen in this Android Studio 3.5.3 screenshot:

[image: Kotlin error]

I tried `@JvmStatic` and `@JvmField` on those `const val` declarations, but the compiler complains that neither are valid for `const` properties.

I get the same results from a `companion object`:

```
class OldTownRoad {
  companion object {
    const val COWBOY_HATS = "from Gucci"
    const val WRANGLER = "on my booty"
  }
}
```

Is there some other Kotlin constant syntax that works when referenced from a Java annotation?

Comment: final val?.....

Comment: Which Kotlin version are you using? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @RickSanchez: `final const val` results in "final is a redundant modifier". Neither that nor `final val` clear up the problem.

Comment: @natario: Kotlin 1.3.61

Comment: @natario: Thanks for pointing out that you couldn't repro it! It appears this is a rogue Android Studio inspection error -- the code compiles fine.

Comment: I'm also using Kotlin 1.3.61 as well and it [works fine for me](https://ibb.co/mG7XP6n). Try checking dependencies? I have ```implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"``` and ```implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'```

Comment: @alvinalvord: I already posted an answer -- looks like it's an Android Studio code inspection bug. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I forgot to see if this was an Android Studio bug. :facepalm:

It turns out that if you run the code, it runs fine. Android Studio 3.5.3 appears to be complaining needlessly.

I filed [a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146923572) to try to get confirmation of the problem.

Many thanks to @natario, whose comment made me realize that this might be an IDE problem!

Comment: Cool! For what it's worth I'm using a slightly older version of AS (still 3.5).

Comment: Oh I see! I also have an older version, 3.3.2

Comment: As of Kotlin 1.3.70 this problem is solved (in Android Studio 3.6.1)