# Kotlin const to static final in Java

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I have this Scope on Dagger:

**ActivityScope.kt**

```
@Scope
annotation class ActivityScope {
    companion object {
        const val ID: String = "Activity"
    }
}
```

**MyClass.java**

```
@ActivityScope
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    MyClass(@Named(ActivityScope.ID) Context context) {
       ...
    }
}
```

The problem is, the compiler is complaining that ActivityScope.ID is not a constant, and indeed, looking at the ByteCode generated by the ActivityScope the ID is not a constant:

**Generated code from Kotlin to Java**

```
public @interface ActivityScope {
   ActivityScope.Companion Companion = ActivityScope.Companion.$$INSTANCE;
   @NotNull
   String ID = "Activity";
```

How to make this *String ID* as a constant?

Comment: Are you *sure* it will not compile? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59522470/115145

Comment: Seems to be an IDE error indeed